# Compression of OData in IIS

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I use dynamic compression in IIS7 and enabled the following lines in the configuration:

```
    <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
        <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
        <staticTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
        </staticTypes>
        <dynamicTypes>
            <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/json; odata=fullmetadata; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
            <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
            <add mimetype="application/atom+xml" enabled="true">
            <add mimetype="application/atom+xml;charset=utf-8" enabled="true">
            <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
        </dynamicTypes>
    </httpCompression>
```

I have an OData controller in Web API which is based off a `ODataController`.

The OData part work fine, but dynamic compression seems not to work on them, the request looks like this:

```
Accept:application/atomsvc+xml;q=0.8, application/json;odata=fullmetadata;q=0.7, application/json;q=0.5, */*;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
DataServiceVersion:3.0
MaxDataServiceVersion:3.0
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
X-SchemaVersion:2.0.0.265
```

And the response like this:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:34862
Content-Type:application/json; odata=fullmetadata; charset=utf-8
DataServiceVersion:3.0
Date:Wed, 11 Jun 2014 16:35:12 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the config you posted are web.config of your application. The most easy solution is to changed "add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"" to "add mimeType="*/*" enabled="true"" in dynamicTypes of config. You can try if it works.

Another solution is to change the config in IIS manager. you can follow:[Here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnablingDynamicCompressionGzipDeflateForWCFDataFeedsODataAndOtherCustomServicesInIIS7.aspx)